# How to add intro animation to my leaderboard

Tags: css

I have a leaderboard code which ranks users ( just a code for learning purposes ) from 1 to 10. Now I want to animate it when it appears ( An Intro animation for each element ). I have literally no experience in animating and I appreciate any code or idea to create a stunning animation.

I've tried simple CSS animation codes but it looks very bad :(

Comment: try [`animate.css`](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: You should know StackOverflow is not a free code making site/forum. Here we help you debug/improve your code so you get the desired result. We do not make 'code' nor 'features' ( like animations ) from scratch. Show us what have you tried, tell us your own idea of how the animation should look like and the community will help you. Otherwise i suggest you search for freelancing $ites, they will be more than happy to help you.